# pywinauto qwidget click triggers no action

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, pywinauto

It is visibly that a QWidget button is pressed and released, unfortunately no action is triggered.

The environment is similar to [find qwidget object text by using pywinauto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983110/find-qwidget-object-text-by-using-pywinauto). The code has resorted to use of absolute coordinates from [How to click a 'next' button of a window using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607979/how-to-click-a-next-button-of-a-window-using-python).

Once the program runs, the target window will get focus. The cursor starts to be somewhere close to the center of the target window. Then it moves to the button, presses the button since the color changes to the down-color. Then it releases the button, and the cursor moves back to the center of window. Only one thing missing, no action is taken from the target window application.

There is one fix: If I move the mouse to the title of the window and click at the right time, the automatic click on the button will trigger a real action. This makes me puzzled as to why this is happening, and unable to think about a solution for it.

```
app1 = Application()
app1.connect(title_re='^Quartus Prime Programmer.*$')
app1.QWidget.print_control_identifiers()

win1 = app1.QWidget
rect1 = win1.rectangle()
coor1 = (rect1.left+64,rect1.top+350) # 64, 350: "add file"
win11 = win1.TopLevelParent()
for i in range(3):
    win11.SetFocus()
    win11.PressMouseInput(coords=coor1)
    time.sleep(1.3)
    win11.ReleaseMouseInput()
    time.sleep(3.0)
```

The code repeats it three time so a human intervention can be easily inserted into the process. 
[image]

Comment: Noticed this about UAC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254091/unable-to-click-button-using-pywinauto-on-a-specific-window-on-windows-8-or-10 but think it is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, the answers you've found are a bit out-of-date. :) pywinauto 0.6.0 was out at the end of 2016 with some recent updates.

Comment: Hmm... The app looks like old Qt4 app that supports MSAA partially. You can see many controls in `Inspect.exe` but texts are not available for many of them.

Answer (score 1):

Qt apps can be automated using `Application(backend='uia')`. Please read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) written specially for pywinauto 0.6.0+ with the new backend. It explains the core concept and many useful tricks.

P.S. I've downloaded this Lite edition app and will try to make an example for you later.

Comment: `app = Application(backend='uia')` works, then the next line `app.connect(title_re='^Quartus Prime Programmer.*$')` fails. have you tried? thanks for chiming in though.

Comment: I see you commented under the question. Very much thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer a solution in python or pywinauto. Here is a temporary workaround using a java robot, just to get it going. The python will call it through a command line `java -jar TestQuartusClick.jar 64 350 1`, where `64 350 1` are the coordinates and call reference number.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestQuartusClick {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 0, y = 0, fn = 0;
        if ( args.length == 3 ) {
            x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            fn = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); /* reference */
        } else {
            System.out.println("java error args size not 3");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "java input %d %d %d", x, y, fn));
        Robot bot;
        try {
            bot = new Robot();
            int mask = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
            bot.mouseMove(x, y);
            bot.mousePress(mask);
            bot.mouseRelease(mask);
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "java clicked %d %d %d", x, y, fn));
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "java error click %d %d %d", x, y, fn));
            //Logger.getLogger(TestQuartusClick.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```